# Application.OnTime - Worksheet_Calculate - Interference

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, events, worksheet-function

`Application.OnTime` only works when Excel is in ready mode. When you use `Worksheet_Calculate()` event Excel is never in ready mode since the worksheet is constantly calculating (in this case). A suggestion is to create a module scoped variable to hold the scheduled time and use `Worksheet_Calculate()` to execute the scheduled task. My goal was to log a row of data using `Application.OnTime` every minute but that never worked since it was interfering with the `Worksheet_Calculate()` events in my other sheets. Need help placing this block of code in my `Worksheet_Calculate()` event and to log the time on another worksheet every minute.

```
Option Explicit

Public DoOnTime As Date
Private Const SchedulePeriod As Date = "00:01:00" ' 1 minute

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim cel As Range, Capture As Range, Ws1 As Worksheet, Ws2 As Worksheet
    
Set Ws1 = Worksheets("Dashboard")
Set Ws2 = Worksheets("Log")

If Now() >= DoOnTime Then
    On Error GoTo safeexit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set Capture = Ws1.Range("A39:Q39") 'Capture this row of data
    With Ws2 'Record the data on this worksheet
    Set cel = .Range("A2") 'First timestamp goes here
    Set cel = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cel.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    cel.Value = Now
    cel.Offset(0, 1).Resize(Capture.Rows.Count, 
    Capture.Columns.Count).Value = Capture.Value
End With
    DoOnTime = Now() + SchedulePeriod
    Debug.Print "Triggered at", Now(), "Scheduled at", DoOnTime
End If
    safeexit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: re this line: `With Worksheets("Ws2")` - do you really have as worksheet named "Ws2" or are you trying to use the variable `Ws2`?  If the later, then it should be `With Ws2`

Comment: Use the variable `Ws2` I updated it. Thanks. It still has a problem crashing excel with this block of code.

Comment: Well, you didn't explain that the code was crashing Excel.  You are probably causing an Event Cascade.  Move the line `On Error GoTo safeexit
Application.EnableEvents = False` to just after `If Now() >= DoOnTime Then`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, your right that was creating the crashing. It is logging correctly but the duration of time isn't set to the correct interval of 1-minute. It appears to be logging at every calculation which is like every second/millisecond.

Comment: The code within the `If Now() >= DoOnTime Then` block executes correctly on schedule.  Of cource the reminder of the code executes every recalc.  Is that what you are refering to?

Comment: The code within the `If Now() >= DoOnTime Then` does not execute on schedule. But the remainder of the code after `If Worksheets("Dashboard").ToggleButton1.Value = True Then` works good it executes every recalc like its suppose to. The schedule period doesn't seem to be in 1-minute intervals.

Comment: My Immediate Window looks like:                                                                     
Triggered at 3/10/2022 5:57:24 PM     Scheduled at 3/10/2022 5:57:24 PM
Triggered at 3/10/2022 5:57:25 PM     Scheduled at 3/10/2022 5:57:25 PM
Triggered at 3/10/2022 5:57:26 PM     Scheduled at 3/10/2022 5:57:26 PM
....and so on. Trying to get it to log (record) every minute to my log sheet.

Comment: That dump shows your schedule times at at 1sec increments.   When I ran your code (cut down to just the scheduling part), it runs at 1min increments.  That tells me that your actual code is not the same as the code you posted

Comment: Yes, your right. I also created a test workbook and just used the scheduling part and it is running in 1min increments. I do have other sheets ~23 that are using the `Worksheet_Calculate()` event (the exact same script as I posted). Do I need to put the scheduling part in those also?

Comment: To clarify, do each of the sheets include the scheduling code?  If so then each will trigger independently.   To verify include the sheet name in the debug, ie `Debug.Print Me.Name & " Triggered" & ...`

Comment: With that many sheets it might be better to use the [Workbook event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetcalculate)

Comment: I got it to work. I just needed to separate the scheduling code on a separate `Worksheet_Calculate()` sheet and not tie it together w/ the other code. No, only one sheet includes this scheduling code. I never thought/knew about a Workbook calculate event. That might work better. If I wanted run this scheduling code only between certain hours of the day how would I do that? Looking to run it between 8:30 to 3:00.